# JAXB marshall List<String> JSON?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I am using JAXB (MoXY) for marshalling/unmarshalling my data in XML and JSON both.

I have a `List<String>` wrapped in a class which I want send over the wire:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "carList")
public class CarsList {

    @XmlValue
    protected List<String> cars;

    public List<String> getCars() {
        if (cars == null) {
            cars = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return cars;
    }

    public void addCar(String carId) {
        if (cars == null) {
            cars = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        if (carId != null) {
            this.cars.add(car);
        }
    }

    public void setCars(List<String> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }
}
```

The XML is coming as expected:

```
<prefix:carList xmlns:prefix="http://www....some prefix namespace...">car1 car2 car3</prefix:carList>
```

But the JSON I am getting is:

```
{
   "prefix:carList" :  "car1 car2 car3"
}
```

My JSON marshaller properties:

```
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, true);
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_MARSHAL_EMPTY_COLLECTIONS, false);
```

But I want my JSON like:

```
{
   "prefix:carList" : [ "car1", "car2", "car3" ]
}
```

I am new to JAXB. What changes do I need to make my JSON as desired ?? I am open to modifying my domain class `CarsList`

Adding `@XmlList` annotation on the list element, also adds its key-name (`cars`) like:

```
{
"prefix:carsList" : {
      "cars" : ["car1", "car2", "car3"]
}
}
```

which is not desired.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this marshaller setting should solve your issue:

```
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME, true);
```