# Jaxb marshall/unmarshall flat map of lists from json

Tags: java, json, jaxb, moxy

I've recently been faced with a tough json (that I don't control, so I have to deal with it):

```
{
    "someOtherParam":"someValue",
    "attributes":
    {
        "language":["fr", "en"],
        "otherParam":["value1", "value2"]
    }
}
```

`attributes` is a map - I don't know what attributes it may contain, so I can't just map it to an object. In Java I believe I need to map is as a `Map<String,List<String>>` somehow.

I've found a [very helpful post](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-using-maps-key-as.html) that allowed me to write an adapter like this:

```
public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapAdapter.AdaptedMap, Map<String, List<String>>> {

  public static class AdaptedMap {
    @XmlVariableNode("key")
    List<AdaptedEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public static class AdaptedEntry {
    @XmlTransient
    public String key;

    @XmlValue
    public List<String> value;
  }

  @Override
  public AdaptedMap marshal(Map<String, List<String>> map) throws Exception {
    AdaptedMap adaptedMap = new AdaptedMap();
    for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      AdaptedEntry adaptedEntry = new AdaptedEntry();
      adaptedEntry.key = entry.getKey();
      adaptedEntry.value = entry.getValue();
      adaptedMap.entries.add(adaptedEntry);
    }
    return adaptedMap;
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, List<String>> unmarshal(AdaptedMap adaptedMap) throws Exception {
    List<AdaptedEntry> adaptedEntries = adaptedMap.entries;
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>(adaptedEntries.size());
    for(AdaptedEntry adaptedEntry : adaptedEntries) {
      map.put(adaptedEntry.key, adaptedEntry.value);
    }
    return map;
  }

}
```

And while this general approach would work for simple values (so a `Map<String,String>` for instance), here on marshalling it insists on mapping the list as a simple element

```
{
    "someOtherParam":"someValue",
    "attributes":
    {
        "language":"fr en",
        "otherParam":"value1 value2"
    }
}
```

So how do I do this correctly?

Comment: But the list is a single element here, isn't it? (e.g. the single String "fr en") You could of course replace the spaces by "," if that is what you want and does not break the format elsewhere.

Comment: @floxbr `"fr en"` is produced by my version of the code, which I'm showing here to show my work so far. What the endpoint I'm talking with expects however is `["fr", "en"]`, and it won't understand me if I send something different.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that part. I'm not really familiar with moxy, but this looks exactly like your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452733/jaxb-marshall-liststring-json

Comment: @floxbr nope - I mean, it would be if I was struggling with just the list as a property of a root element. But being already inside an `AdaptedEntry` with `@XmlVariableNode` makes this problem be on another level entirely.